Storybook a11y addon not failing on custom object-alt rule
I'm using Storybook with the @storybook/addon-a11y addon to ensure my components meet accessibility standards. I've enabled the object-alt rule and added a custom check for it, but it doesn't seem to fail even when the custom check returns false.
Here is my preview.ts file:
import { setCompodocJson } from "@storybook/addon-docs/angular";
import docJson from "../documentation.json";
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { IconModule } from 'carbon-components-angular/icon';
import { ButtonModule, TabsModule } from "carbon-components-angular";

setCompodocJson(docJson);

// Function to add the "white" theme class to the body
const applyTheme = () => {
  const document: Document = window.document;
  document.body.classList.add('white');
};

applyTheme();

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      toc: true, //  Enables the table of contents
    },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
    a11y: {
      config: {
        rules: [
          {
            id: 'wcag2aa',
            enabled: true,
          },
          {
            id: 'object-alt',
            enabled: true, // Ensure the object-alt rule is enabled
          },
        ],
        checks: [
          {
            id: 'object-alt',
            evaluate: function (node, options) {
              console.log('Evaluating object-alt for node:', node);
              // Custom evaluation logic for object-alt
              return false; // Simulate a failure
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  tags: ['autodocs'], //  Enables auto-generated documentation for all stories
};

export const decorators = [
  moduleMetadata({
    imports: [IconModule, TabsModule, ButtonModule],
  }),
];

export default preview;

Problem:
Despite the evaluate function returning false, the object-alt rule does not show as failed in my Storybook page. I've added console.log statements to verify that the evaluate function is being called, and it is.

Steps Taken:
Verified that the object-alt rule is enabled.
Added custom evaluation logic that returns false.
3. Checked the browser console to ensure the evaluate function is being executed.
Question:
Why is the object-alt rule not showing as failed in my Storybook page, and how can I ensure it correctly fails when the custom check returns false?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
